# When I am using this program for string it isn't working

Tags: c, scanf

so today I made a program that basically gets the right password from the user. It works well with integers but when I rewrite the code for working with strings it isn't working. I have tried many different ways but nothing works. can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char Guess[8];
  char Password[] = "password";
  int Guesscount = 3;
  int Granted = 1;

  while (Guess != Password && Granted == 1) {
    if (Guesscount > 0) {
      printf("Enter password: ");
      scanf("%s", Guess);
      Guesscount = Guesscount - 1;
      if (Guess != Password && Guesscount > 0) {
        printf("Wrong Password, you have %d try left.\n", Guesscount);
      }
    } else {
      Granted = 0;
    }
  }

  if (Granted == 0) {
    printf("Denied");
  } else {
    printf("Granted");
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read about `strcmp()` function for comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two strings in `C` use the `strcmp(str1, str2)`, it compares two strings character by character. If the strings are equal, the function returns 0.

Instead of this `Guess != Password` use this `strcmp(Guess , Password) == 0`.

Comment: Thanks man it actually worked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings with `==` and `!=` operators in C. For that purpose use `strcmp()` function which is defined in `string.h` header file.

That was the reason integers were working but string weren't. You can say that you cannot compare arrays with those equality operators.

Also, you are using `scanf()` function to take user input with format specifier `"%s"`, which isn't very good, you should put a `limit`, for an example in your case `"%8s"`. Also, to store 8 characters long password you need to make `Guess` at-least 9 character long.

Once, password was denied and `Guesscount` is > 0, then use `memset()` to clear `Guess` so that it can read new data.

Final Code Should Be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char Guess[9];
  memset(Guess, 0, 9);
  char Password[] = "password";
  int Guesscount = 3;
  int Granted = 1;

  while (strcmp(Guess, Password) != 0 && Granted == 1) {
    if (Guesscount > 0) {
      printf("Enter password: ");
      scanf("%8s", Guess);
      Guesscount = Guesscount - 1;
      if (strcmp(Guess, Password) != 0 && Guesscount > 0) {
        printf("Wrong Password, you have %d try left.\n", Guesscount);
        memset(Guess, 0, 9);
      }
    } else {
      Granted = 0;
    }
  }

  if (Granted == 0) {
    printf("Denied");
  } else {
    printf("Granted");
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: @SakibHasan If that worked mark my answer as correct.